# PPA package update throwing "Invalid SHA" on import

Tags: ppa, deb

I'm trying to update a package on my PPA, but the import fails with the following error:

```
2019-06-26 05:33:26 INFO    Starting job.
2019-06-26 05:33:26 INFO    Getting exising bzr branch from central store.
2019-06-26 05:33:26 INFO    [chan bzr SocketAsChannelAdapter] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
2019-06-26 05:33:26 INFO    35 bytes transferred
2019-06-26 05:33:29 INFO    [chan bzr SocketAsChannelAdapter] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
2019-06-26 05:33:30 INFO    Importing branch.
2019-06-26 05:33:31 INFO    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/scripts/code-import-worker.py", line 106, in <module>
    sys.exit(script.main())
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/scripts/code-import-worker.py", line 101, in main
    return import_worker.run()
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/lib/lp/codehosting/codeimport/worker.py", line 554, in run
    return self._doImport()
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/lib/lp/codehosting/codeimport/worker.py", line 757, in _doImport
    inter_branch.fetch(limit=revision_limit)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/branch.py", line 722, in fetch
    self.fetch_objects(stop_revision, fetch_tags=fetch_tags, limit=limit)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/branch.py", line 745, in fetch_objects
    determine_wants, self.source.mapping, limit=limit)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/fetch.py", line 715, in fetch_objects
    progress=lambda text: report_git_progress(pb, text))
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/remote.py", line 461, in fetch_objects
    lambda x: os.write(fd, x), progress)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/remote.py", line 451, in fetch_pack
    pack_data, progress)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/remote.py", line 270, in fetch_pack
    graph_walker, pack_data, progress)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dulwich/client.py", line 1413, in fetch_pack
    lambda: False)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dulwich/client.py", line 574, in _handle_upload_pack_head
    have = next(graph_walker)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dulwich/object_store.py", line 1173, in next
    ps = self.get_parents(ret)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/fetch.py", line 708, in <lambda>
    lambda sha: store[sha].parents)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/object_store.py", line 674, in __getitem__
    _check_expected_sha(sha, commit)
  File "/srv/importd.launchpad.net/production/launchpad-rev-18991/bzrplugins/git/object_store.py", line 155, in _check_expected_sha
    expected_sha))
AssertionError: Invalid sha for <Commit f896f482b8dffbfb95809764b42ffa73e0cc008e>: 606c547e4e523ce6ec67f1f5142532b0975b319a
Import failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.error.ProcessTerminated: A process has ended with a probable error condition: process ended with exit code 1.
```

I'm not quite sure what to do to fix this and I can't seem to find any relevant information on the error message. Any hints or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an issue with cross-synchronization between bzr and git. In my case, my primary source was a git repository and I had no need of the bzr repository, so I changed my synchronization target on launchpad to git and changed the build recipe to the git builder and everything worked fine.